# Laravel in vpc, access sqs without programatic access

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, vpc

I have a Laravel app running on an ec2 instance inside a VPC. Now I want to connect to an SQS from the app. Using programmatic access seems to work but I want to use the SQS endpoint, without having to use the key and the secret.

Technically speaking this should be possible with the AWS resources being linked together. Any idea how to set this up in Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) (basically a set of policies) which you attach to your [EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). The policies you include would have a section for access to your SQS queue (or at least certain actions on it in SQS). This effectively allows temporary credentials to be given to the instance without having to have them in code.

The role might look something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
            ...<any other actions>
        ],
        "Resource": <SQS Queue ARN>
    }
]
}
```

You attach this role to your EC2 instance in the EC2 console - select instance, go to `Instance Settings > Attach/Replace IAM Role`

Comment: Thanks, that I'm clear. but in Laravel how to configure this?

Comment: IAM is (pretty much) software agnostic; you shouldn't need to configure Laravel at all (although my memory of that framework is rusty!) - this is a configuration that lives in AWS and is attached to the instances (or whatever) you're running your   application from.